# PyTorch - AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: python, sum, pytorch, attributeerror

I am running a deep learning model using PyTorch and getting the following error.

```
'correct+=(yhat==y_test).sum().int()'
```

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'

Below is a larger snippet of the code.

'''

```
for x_test, y_test in validation_loader:
            model.eval()
            z = model(x_test)
            yhat = torch.max(z.data,1)
            correct+=(yhat==y_test).sum().int()
            accuracy = correct / n_test
            accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think in this line

```
yhat = torch.max(z.data,1)
```

you're attempting to get `torch.argmax()`. I guess you're trying to get the predictions in `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]` format, and not the maximum probability of your batch.

Comment: Do you think 

_, yhat = torch.max(z.data,1)

would fix that?

Comment: try `yhat = torch.argmax(z.data, 1)`

Comment: thanks, I am trying that now, it's takes about 45 mins for it to run through. I will let you know how it goes

Comment: it's been running for 2 hours now, and hasn't resolved.... so i don't think that is the issue.... or it's caused a different one??  any thoughts?

Comment: How would I know

Answer (score 0):

While training there is grad which should be neglected.
It may solve the problem.

```
 pred = model(image)
 _, prediction = torch.max(pred, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

torch.eq() returns tensor, torch.equal() returns boolean.